# ffmpeg version 2.6.8 : Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description matches no streams

Tags: ffmpeg

I am not getting why this isn't working.. I have tried to get the video streams with [0:v]/[0:1]/[0:v:0] & the audio streams with [0:a]/[0:0]/[0:0:0].
nothing worked.

Explaining the inputs:

1.1st input stream is a video that can be of varying resolution on which the filter adds a padding on to make it 600:480.

2.2nd input is an overlay png which is already at 5:4 ratio.. just making it 600:480 before it gets overlaid in the filter.

3.3rd & 4th ones are also videos which I don't care if they get stretched.. n they are getting stretched to 600:480.

4.so finally there are 3 streams 1 overlaid video 2 stretched videos which needs to be concatenated.

here's the command :

```
ffmpeg 
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612.mp4' 
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612_overlay.png' 
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines1.mp4' 
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines11.mp4' 
-filter_complex
"[0:v]trim=0:138,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]atrim=0:138,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[v0]scale='gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600+lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih):lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480+gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw)',pad='600:480:(600-gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600-lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih))/2:(480-lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480-gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw))/2:black'[x];[1:v]scale=600:480[y];[x][y]overlay=0:0[z];[2:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x0];[3:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x1];[x0][2:a][z][a0][x1][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" 
-map "[v]" 
-map "[a]" 
-c:v libx264 
-shortest /home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612_final.mp4
```

this is the complete error I am getting :

```
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description  [0:v]trim=0:138,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]atrim=0:138,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[v0]scale='gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600+lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih):lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480+gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw)',pad='600:480:(600-gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600-lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih))/2:(480-lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480-gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw))/2:black'[x];[1:v]scale=600:480[y];[x][y]overlay=0:0[z];[2:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x0];[3:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x1];[x0][2:a][z][a0][x1][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.
```

also there are these warnings:

```
[Parsed_setsar_9 @ 0x219fba0] num:den syntax is deprecated, please use num/den or named options instead
[Parsed_setsar_11 @ 0x21a4840] num:den syntax is deprecated, please use num/den or named options instead
```

Complete log as requested :

```
[root@cloud ~]# ffmpeg -i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612.mp4' -i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612_overlay.png' -i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines1.mp4' -i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines11.mp4' -filter_complex \ "[0:v]trim=0:138,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]atrim=0:138,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[v0]scale='gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600+lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih):lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480+gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw)',pad='600:480:(600-gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600-lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih))/2:(480-lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480-gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw))/2:black'[x];[1:v]scale=600:480[y];[x][y]overlay=0:0[z];[2:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x0];[3:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x1];[x0][2:a][z][a0][x1][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -shortest /home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612_final.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-08-21 02:23:24
  Duration: 00:02:17.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 417 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 318 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-08-21 02:23:24
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Input #1, png_pipe, from '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612_overlay.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba, 600x479, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2018-01-31 22:40:09
  Duration: 00:00:04.90, start: 0.103811, bitrate: 846 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 1920x1080, 827 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-01-31 22:40:10
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines11.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2018-01-31 22:40:09
  Duration: 00:00:04.90, start: 0.103811, bitrate: 846 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/bt709), 1920x1080, 827 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-01-31 22:40:10
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
[Parsed_setsar_9 @ 0x17c8ba0] num:den syntax is deprecated, please use num/den or named options instead
[Parsed_setsar_11 @ 0x17cd840] num:den syntax is deprecated, please use num/den or named options instead
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description  [0:v]trim=0:138,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[0:a]atrim=0:138,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];[v0]scale='gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600+lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih):lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480+gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw)',pad='600:480:(600-gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600-lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih))/2:(480-lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480-gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw))/2:black'[x];[1:v]scale=600:480[y];[x][y]overlay=0:0[z];[2:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x0];[3:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x1];[x0][2:a][z][a0][x1][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a] matches no streams.
```

Comment: You should start with some MUCH simpler filter just testing the stream selection. Your filter is so big, the error could have many causes. Plus, the error doesn't say your [0:a] is wrong and there is only a warning about it, not an error. You also didn't tell your FFmpeg version.

Comment: please check the question now.. have added some explanations on the inputs & filters

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your other inputs don't have audio. A dummy audio has to be supplied.

```
ffmpeg \
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612.mp4' \
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612_overlay.png' \
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines1.mp4' \
-i '/home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/user/736/video/Lines11.mp4' \
-f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc \
-filter_complex  \
  "[0:v]trim=0:138,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
   [0:a]atrim=0:138,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0]; \
   [v0]scale='gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600+lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih):lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480+gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw)',pad='600:480:(600-gte(iw/ih\,600/480)*600-lt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((480*iw)/ih))/2:(480-lte(iw/ih\,600/480)*480-gt(iw/ih\,600/480)*((600*ih)/iw))/2:black'[x];[1:v]scale=600:480[y];[x][y]overlay=0:0[z];[2:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x0];[3:v]scale=600:480,setsar=1:1[x1];[x0][4:a][z][a0][x1][4:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -shortest /home/vidinflux/public_html/assets/temp/2018020116464612/2018020116464612_final.mp4
```

Comment: thanks for pointing the blank audio part.. wasn't being able to differentiate them from the working examples till now

Comment: do you know how to detect if it doesn't have an audio stream. so that I can set the null source accordingly?

Comment: Use `ffprobe -show_entries stream=codec_type "input.mp4" -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0 | grep audio | wc -l`

Comment: hey man after using -f lavfi -i anullsrc.. the rendering is going on n on.. it's producing like 200mb file for inputs of barely 15mb.. also that 200mb file is corrupted.

Comment: Right. That's why you need the `-t 0.1` in my answer.

Comment: I got `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [1:0]volume=0.5[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first matches no streams` with the following command `ffmpeg -i ./video1.mp4 -i ./Forbidden.mp3 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[1:0]volume=0.5[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first" -map 0:v:0 output.mp4`, could you help please?

Comment: @ahbon does video1.mp4 have audio? It seems it doesn't. That's why it can't get the audio from input[0]

Comment: Not working .. still giving same error.
E/mobile-ffmpeg: Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0:v]scale=720x480,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=720x480,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]scale=720x480,setsar=1[v2];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 matches no streams.

Comment: @Gyan can you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71217250/track-and-add-silent-audio-in-video-using-ffmpeg-and-ffprobe-combined-single-com

Comment: @Gyan can you check this  command   -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex " [0:v]trim=0ms:6000ms,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale='min(720,iw)':'min(1280,ih)':force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:-1:-1:color=#aaaaaa,setsar=1[vout0];[0:a]atrim=0:6000,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0];  [vout0][a0]concat=n=1:v=1:a=1[vout1][a] " -map [vout1] -map [a] -vsync 2 -strict -2 -preset ultrafast

Comment: @Gyan Please help me with this one : 
`-i  videoPath1 -i videoPath2 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=720:1280,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[v0]; [1:v]scale=720:1280,fps=fps=30,setsar=1[v1]; [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]"  outputfilePath`

I am having issue, can't figure out with your solution alteration’s. Did many  tries.